# I am trying to identify multiple values which were selected from a checkbox using PHP

Tags: php, html

I am trying to identify multiple values which were selected from a checkbox using PHP, here is my code below, you can see i have attempted to create a custom string when Java and C/C++ is selected

```
<form action="#" method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="C/C++"><label>C/C++</label><br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="Java"><label>Java</label><br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="PHP"><label>PHP</label><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){//to run PHP script on submit
    if(!empty($_POST['check_list'])){
        // Loop to store and display values of individual checked checkbox.
        foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $selected){
            echo $selected."<br>";
        }
    }
}

if(in_array('C/C++', $_POST['check_list'])) {
    echo 'C/C++ was checked!';
} elseif(in_array('C/C++','Java',$_POST['check_list'])){
    echo 'C/C++ and Java was checked!'; 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't give multiple needles to `in_array()`.

Also, if both `C/C++` and `Java` are selected, the first `if` will succeed, so it will never try the `elseif`. If you want a structure like that, you need to test the larger group first.

You can use nested `if` instead.

```
if(in_array('C/C++', $_POST['check_list'])) {
    if (in_array('Java', $_POST['check_list'])) {
        echo 'C/C++ and Java were checked!';
    } else {
        echo 'C/C++ was checked!';
    }
}
```

A more general way to test if multiple items are in the array is with `array_intersect`:

```
if (!empty(array_intersect(['C/C++', 'Java'], $_POST['check_list'])) {
    echo 'C/C++ and Java were checked!';
}
```